# In bootstrap, can I transpose a vertical col-lg-2 to a horizontal row when the screen shrinks width?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

On a large screen, my layout looks nice, like this:

```
---------------
|col-lg-10||A |
|         ||B |
|         ||C |
---------------
```

When I shrink my screen width slightly, I want it to rearrange like this:

```
-----------
|col-lg-10|
|         |
|         |
-----------
|A ||B ||C |
```

However, right now it rearranges like this:

```
-----------
|col-lg-10|
|         |
|         |
-----------
|A |
|B |
|C |
```

Here's my current grid layout:

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div id="mainChart">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-auto">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="A">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="B">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="C">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've fiddled around with different combinations of rows and columns, but I can't seem to get it to satisfy both conditions at the same time. Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
    <div id="mainChart">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-lg-2 col-sm-12 d-flex d-lg-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="A">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="B">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="C">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, d-flex is what I was missing!

Comment: One note: you need the class on the second column to be this: col-lg-2 col-sm-12 d-flex d-lg-block. Otherwise, the flex will always apply and on large screens the small items still stack sideways.

Comment: I can't accept the answer yet, because it was too fast. I'll accept when the timer is up

Comment: sorry i missed it